# Append output for a Jupyter cell without erasing the old one when running

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When you run the code in the Jupyther cell the output below the cell is erased and a new one is added. Is there some magic to append new output without overwriting the old one?

Comment: I think you need to state your goal for wanting to do that? There's ways you could capture the output using `%%capture` magic and possibly bring it back in for a re-run. However, you'd have to build in accessing it. And handling the first time the cell is run. It's so convoluted that there is probably a better way to achieve your ultimate goal. It sounds like you just want an IPython console?

Comment: Continued... Do you just need to see the previous activity and not necessarily use it? If that is the case, **in JupyterLab** you can toggle on ‘Show All Kernel Activity’ for an attached console, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez) to get ideas how you can use the attached console.

Comment: Continued...You can try a very current JupyterLab version backed by a full python kernel right in your browser by following [this link](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/ece14f28f9b751a11646270eb839) and letting the session spin up. Then when the interface opens you can start a new notebook and attach a console.